# Technique for making roots\vines for wargaming backgrounds

Tags: technique-selection, model-building

I'm looking for techniques that can be used to make roots or vines that hang down from the ceiling, on a 35mm miniature scale. Mostly the vines themselves, I have the leafs covered.

The kind that a hero might use to swing across a booby trap, or which an eldritch creature might use to walk across the ceiling.

For visual reference, the jungle creepers behind King Louie in the ruined temple scenes from the Disney animated version of the Jungle Book, or the creepers that Tarzan swings from in Disney's Tarzan.

Comment: Would the dimensions translate to something close to 1mm diameter? If so, that's in the size range of very heavy thread or very thin twine. It can be stiffened, and the color fine-tuned, by soaking it in diluted paint and glue, and letting it dry in the shape you want.

Comment: And in case fixer1234's idea doesn't work for you, can you explain why?

Comment: I'm looking for something with more detail, so an exaggerated diameter would be preferable. 2-3mm., maybe.

Comment: Roughly what length do you want these (some methods are good for any length, some only for relatively short lengths)? Will they be protected, or exposed to handling/accidents, or could the diorama be bumped or moved  (how "unbreakable" do they need to be; would something brittle or delicate work)? Would the surface texture of string pass for twisted vines (the twist can be loosened), or are you looking to create a specific surface texture?

Answer (score 5):

Look for wire core twine in the garden department or a hobby / craft store.

It's not expensive for the amount you get and comes in various materials, thicknesses and colors. Garden departments usually have hemp or sisal twine, which has a more natural look at scale. Craft stores may only have shiny polished twine for basket weaving or similar crafts.

Due to the wire core the twine will hold the shape you bend it into and due to the fiber mantle paint and glue sticks well to it. Just be careful when cutting the twine or you may ruin your scissors.

Here are 2 examples:

[image]
Click for bigger image. ([image source](https://www.joom.com/en/products/5ea939101436d40101f6c6d8))

[image]
Click for bigger image. ([image source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B097XQ4DBG))

Comment: Similar idea, another source: paper-wrapped wire in various diameters in this range are sold as stems for making artificial flowers. Available online (search "paper wrapped floral wire"). Realistic for vines.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question again, I suddenly remembered these toys I used to play with. A search pointed out they're known as '**fuzzy sticks**'. They are bendable metal wires of approximately 15-20 cm long, and covered in often brightly coloured 'fuzz':

[image: macro photo of fuzz sticks of the green variety]

More images [here](https://www.ecosia.org/images?q=Neon%20fuzzy%20sticks).
They come in white as well, which might be easier to colour. You can probably find them in a variety of lengths as well. I believe their diameter, the fuzz included, is around 3 mm.

Comment: I see them more commonly labelled "chenille stems" or "pipe cleaners" here